# Negative margin-right needs to be width+4 pixels?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm having problems with a 2-column layout, using display-style="inline-block".
I have this html:

```
<div class="A">tekst</div>
<div class="B">tekst</div>
```

with css:

```
.A {
   background-color: blue;
   height: 200px;
   width: 250px;
   padding-left: 25px;
   margin-right: -254px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   z-index: 1;
}

.B {
   background-color: red;
   height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
   padding-left: 300px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   position: relative;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eaFn9/9/

But as you can see, the width of the first div is 250 pixels, but it needs a margin-right of -254px before the second div is shown "next" to it.

Why is this? I cannot figure it out. Also, most examples do not use the box-sizing, but if I remove it, the layout goes awry again.

I am using Chrome, but it seems to work the same in FF and Safari too.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Michael

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: It seems that adding "body { font-size: 0; }" solves it for most browsers, but makes the problem worse in Safari (it now needs -255px for margin-right in order to work).

Comment: `font-size:0` also doesn't work for older Operas (it will use its minimum font size instead). Anyway, Fabrizio's answer is correct, even though I wouldn't call it "fighting" the space. You just need to remove the space, that's all.

Comment: Turns out only Safari for Windows has problems with font-size: 0 (a bug?). Safari for Mac and iOS works 'normally'. So I'll go with this solution for now (who uses Safari for Windows anyway ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attemps to find the problem, I bet you have some blank or even some Enter keystroke between the 2 divs. This problem is very hard to find out. So to solve it you just need to clear all that blank or Enter keystroke so that the 2 div tags have to be close next to each other:

```
<!-- place 2 divs close to each other without anything between. -->
<div class="A">tekst</div><div class="B">tekst</div>
```

Here is the [expectedly working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaFn9/13/)

Comment: Not much of a bet really, as the return is clearly visible between the OP's divs.

Comment: This seems to be the solution, but I do think it is weird for HTML to assume that a return between div's should be interpreted as a space.
Anyway, the problem now is that the HTML is generated and I cannot always make sure there are no spaces or anything between divs.

Comment: All white space (return, linefeed, tab) is interpreted as a space. That's how HTML works. Not just between elements, but also between words inside an element. (Put 2 words in a html file on separate lines, then they will be displayed on on line, with a space inbetween.)

Comment: If you don't have any control over the generated HTML, would it be possible to remove the whitespace node with Javascript, after loading?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody with the same problem:

It seems that adding 'font-size: 0' to the parent container fixes it for every browser, just not for Safari for Windows (all other Safaris work as expected).
Make sure that you reset the font-size to a sensible value inside the child divs if you want to have text in them (so in my example, both divs A and B would have font-size: 14px; for instance to show the text).
I assume (I have not done any research at all) this is a bug in Safari for Windows, as it's the only Safari with this issue.